# Timezone Handling - Is it the correct way?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

This is my first time in handling time zones. Here is the scenario:

1. Server + Database is in UTC timezone
2. Client 1 is in IST
   Client 2 is in EST
3. Data stored by EST client should show correctly to client in IST and vice versa
4. Server runs cron job and reads data from database. It needs to show notifications to both EST and IST clients respective to their timezones correctly

### Technology

1. Server OS - Ubuntu (EC2)
2. Database - MySQL (UTC)
3. Backend server - Node.js
4. Frontend - Angular.jS

### What I thought

1. In database, maintain two columns:  created_at, timezone_offset

   - created_at will store everything in UTC
   - offset will store difference in UTC and respective timezones
     example: offset for IST = 330 (in minutes) => 5 hour 30 minutes
2. Whenever send a request to server with date:

   - pick local date time (created_at)
   - find offset from UTC
   - convert created_at to UTC (using moment)
   - send converted created_at , offset to server
   - store created_at , offset in database as it is
3. To run cron on server

   - read records from database using created_at + offset
4. To return API response

   - Return created_at (which is in UTC), offset for every record in json response
   - Client to show date time using created_at + offset (using moment)

Is it the correct way of handling timezone?

Should I use datetime datatype for created_at in MySQL?

Comment: Your third bullet is unclear. "Data stored by EST client should show correctly to client in IST and vice versa" - what is "correctly"? The local time as per the client that stored the value, or the local time corresponding to that instant in the viewing client's own time zone? Working out the correct implementation requires careful specification of the requirements first.

Comment: You should save the datetime in UTC and convert the timezones when selected.. I assume you store timezone offset in a table for a account?

Comment: Make sure you understand the effects of daylight saving time.  Storing a time with an offset is fine - as long as you never assume that offset is valid for *other* points in time.  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Yes, I store timezone offset in every table where I am store datetime

Comment: @JonSkeet If it is 9 am in EST, it is 6:30 PM in IST. Here I mean, data stored by IST client at 6:30 pm should show as 9 am to EST client

Comment: Right. In that case, storing the UTC value may well be fine. It's not clear why you need to also store the offset - if you're scheduling cron jobs based on *both* time zones. Also, if your cron jobs need to be based on the actual time zone (e.g. "Daily at the same local time of day that I created the record") then you need to store the time zone ID (e.g. Europe/London) rather than the offset - because the offset can change over time.